# Does a sequence with no limit points eventually become monotonic?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

A common definition for the limit point of a sequence is that a number $x$ is a limit point of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ if there exists a subsequence that converges to $x$. Intuitively, it appears that if a sequence has no limit points then for some $N$ the sequence is monotonic for all $n\geq N$. Is this true?

Formally speaking, by the Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem $\#\{n \in \mathbb{N}:x_n \in [-K,K]\}<\infty$ for every $K>0$. Is this fact sufficient to imply that $x_n$ must explode in a monotone manner eventually?

Comment: What about $(-n)^n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, take $\{1,-1,2,-2,...\}$.

Comment: I thought of this type of counterexample but my brain connected the dots (1,-1,2,..) with lines so that it appeared that it had to have limit points. I should have thought about it a little bit more. Thanks